# Flutter background fetch giving exception in headless event

Tags: flutter, dart, background-fetch

I am working in flutter background fetch but it is giving me some error in headless task.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.Application android.app.Activity.getApplication()' on a null object reference

Application.java
package com.xxxx.xxxxapp;

```
import com.transistorsoft.flutter.backgroundfetch.BackgroundFetchPlugin;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    BackgroundFetchPlugin.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I've found the following thread https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/issues/35
It says some of the plugins have to use registrar.activity() != null for headless to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Headless events on Android and iOS is yet to be supported in Flutter due to OS level limitations. Here's the [open ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32164) for this feature request. A workaround would be to wake the app using [WorkManager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) and execute the [background](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) task.